# Filtering from data

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

DataFrame part:

```
    date            power
56  21/12/2011      214.4
57  22/12/2011      215.3
58  23/12/2011      216.2
59  24/12/2011      217.4
60  25/12/2011      219.7
61  26/12/2011      220.3
62  27/12/2011      220.7
63  28/12/2011      221.2
64  29/12/2011      221.7
65  30/12/2011      222.6
66  31/12/2011      226.2
67   1/01/2012      226.7
68   2/01/2012      227.5
69   3/01/2012      230.4
70   4/01/2012      231.2
71   5/01/2012      233.9
72   6/01/2012      235.5
```

This is my data's part. I want to pick the dates including `2011`. How can I do it without doing like `data[0:x]` you know.

```
for i in data['date']:
    if '2011' in i and i in data['date']:
        print(i)
```

I've tried to do something like this but output was empty.

Comment: `df[df.date.dt.year.isin([2011])]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas.Series.str.contains`:

```
df[df['date'].str.contains('2011')]
```

Output:

```
          date  power
56  21/12/2011  214.4
57  22/12/2011  215.3
58  23/12/2011  216.2
59  24/12/2011  217.4
60  25/12/2011  219.7
61  26/12/2011  220.3
62  27/12/2011  220.7
63  28/12/2011  221.2
64  29/12/2011  221.7
65  30/12/2011  222.6
66  31/12/2011  226.2
```